# access sql query horizontal to vertical

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a mapping table

```
EK_ID   CS      EK_ID-CS    
1001    1071    1001_1071   
1001    1015    1001_1015
1004    1061    1004_1061
1004    1007    1004_1007
1004    1006    1004_1006
1004    1005    1004_1005
1005    1011    1005_1011
1005    1010    1005_1010
1006    1013    1006_1013
1006    1012    1006_1012
```

And Table B, which has common field EK_ID.

```
EK_ID   S1      S2        S3    S4
1001    0.94    0.03    0.01    
1004    0.96    8.12    38.10   0.06
1005    1       2.30        
1006    1       2.47
```

Inner join till field S1 gives the result

```
 EK_ID  CS     EK_ID-CS S1

1001    1071    1001_1071   0.94
1001    1015    1001_1015   0.94
1004    1061    1004_1061   0.96
1004    1007    1004_1007   0.96
1004    1006    1004_1006   0.96
1004    1005    1004_1005   0.96
1005    1011    1005_1011   1
1005    1010    1005_1010   1
1006    1013    1006_1013   1
1006    1012    1006_1012   1
```

I'm trying to write columns S2,S3,S4 values in table B as one column S2 , vertical like below

```
 EK_ID  CS        EK_ID-CS  S1       S2
1001    1071    1001_1071   0.94    0.03
1001    1015    1001_1015   0.94    0.01
1004    1061    1004_1061   0.96    
1004    1007    1004_1007   0.96    8.12
1004    1006    1004_1006   0.96    38.10
1004    1005    1004_1005   0.96    0.06
1005    1011    1005_1011   1      2.30
1005    1010    1005_1010   1   
1006    1013    1006_1013   1      2.47
1006    1012    1006_1012   1
```

How do I represent in a access sql query?

Comment: Edit your question with the query you have used to generate the intermediate result.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get your answer

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is access he might not have SQL

Comment: @Hogan, MS Access comes equipped by default to Jet/ACE SQL engine.

Comment: @Parfait - yes I know this... I guess I miss-spoke.  I should have said "he might not have any idea how to retrieve the SQL from his query."

Comment: To the OP, if you are using a wizard to create query, the result is a saved query object, viewable in Navigation Pane. Find query in pane, right click it and open in Design view and in Home tab select 'SQL View' (or at bottom right is a SQL option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a derived table that calculates a row count and conditionally uses `RowCount` to retrieve `S` columns. This should be compliant in most SQL dialects, simply change Access' `IIF()` to ANSI-SQL's `CASE/WHEN`:

```
SELECT EK_ID, CS, [EK_ID-CS], S1,
       IIF(RowCount = 2, dTS2, 
           IIF(RowCount = 3, dTS3, 
               IIF(RowCount = 4, dTS4, NULL))) As S2
FROM 
    (SELECT TableA.EK_ID, TableA.CS, TableA.[EK_ID-CS], TableB.S1, 
           TableB.S2 As dTS2, TableB.S3 As dTS3, TableB.S4 As dTS4,
           (SELECT Count(*) + 1 FROM TableA t2 
            WHERE t2.EK_ID = TableA.EK_ID AND t2.CS >= TableA.CS) As RowCount
    FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.EK_ID = TableB.EK_ID
    ORDER BY TableA.EK_ID, TableA.CS DESC
    ) As DerivedTable
```

**Output**

```
EK_ID   CS      EK_ID-CS    S1      S2
1001    1071    1001_1071   0.94    0.03
1001    1015    1001_1015   0.94    0.01
1004    1061    1004_1061   0.96    8.12
1004    1007    1004_1007   0.96    38.1
1004    1006    1004_1006   0.96    0.06
1004    1005    1004_1005   0.96    
1005    1011    1005_1011   1       2.3
1005    1010    1005_1010   1   
1006    1013    1006_1013   1       2.47
1006    1012    1006_1012   1
```